# how to access private variables with out using friend function in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Point
    {
    friend void ChangePrivate( Point & );
    public:
    Point( void ) : m_i(0) {}
    void PrintPrivate( void ){cout << m_i << endl; }

private:
int m_i;
};

void ChangePrivate ( Point &i ) { i.m_i++; }

int main()
{
     Point sPoint;
     sPoint.PrintPrivate();
     ChangePrivate(sPoint);
    sPoint.PrintPrivate();
}
```

here is the example how to access private variables using friend function how to use without using friend function?

Comment: Why on earth do you need to do this?

Comment: Add a public getter/setter!

Comment: see http://bloglitb.blogspot.ro/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `friend` is there specifically to bypass access restrictions imposed by `private` and `protected` access control.

If you would like to access private variables without using `friend`, add *public* accessors to the class itself: this is the most common and intended way of accessing private variables:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point( void ) : m_i(0) {}
    void PrintPrivate( void ){cout << m_i << endl; }
    int getI() {return m_i;}
    void setI(int _i) {m_i = _i;}
private:
    int m_i;
};
...
Point sPoint;
sPoint.setI(sPoint.getI()+1);
```

Comment: without using public accessor also

Comment: @user1670364 If there was a reliable way to do it without using a `friend`, why would the designers of the C++ language introduce `friend` in the first place? You can play around with offsets and pointers (see other answers), but ultimately you need to get the offset of a *private* variable, which is supposed to be hidden. If you could get it without `friend` or public accessors, the variable wouldn't be private any longer.

Comment: Actually, there is a reliable, legal way - http://bloglitb.blogspot.ro/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Wow, that nasty trick is so screwed up! It's strange that it is allowed in the first place: I suspect it's a "bug" in the standard.

Comment: Yup, I think of it as a bug in the standard as well... but until it's fixed, it's legal.

Comment: @user1670364: Don't put extra requirements in comments to answers, put them in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Access control does not apply to arguments to explicit template instantiations (`[temp.explicit]/12`). This can be exploited to give public access to private members ([courtesy of litb](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html)):

First some setup code:

```
template<typename Tag>
struct result {
  /* export it ... */
  typedef typename Tag::type type;
  static type ptr;
};

template<typename Tag>
typename result<Tag>::type result<Tag>::ptr;

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type p>
struct rob : result<Tag> {
  /* fill it ... */
  struct filler {
    filler() { result<Tag>::ptr = p; }
  };
  static filler filler_obj;
};

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type p>
typename rob<Tag, p>::filler rob<Tag, p>::filler_obj;
```

Now the definition of `Point`:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point() : m_i(0) {}
    void PrintPrivate(){cout << m_i << endl; }
private:
    int m_i;
};
```

Now fill in `result<Pointm_i>::ptr` by explicitly instantiating `rob<Pointm_i, &Point::m_i>` -- this is an explicit template instantiation, so access control does not apply:

```
struct Pointm_i { typedef int Point::*type; };
template class rob<Pointm_i, &Point::m_i>;
```

And access the private members:

```
void ChangePrivate ( Point &i ) { (i.*result<Pointm_i>::ptr)++; }

int main()
{
     Point sPoint;
     sPoint.PrintPrivate();
     ChangePrivate(sPoint);
     sPoint.PrintPrivate();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a standard compliant hack ([source](http://bloglitb.blogspot.ro/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html)):

```
template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type M>
struct Rob { 
  friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) {
    return M;
  }
};

class Point
{
public:
    Point( void ) : m_i(0) {}
    void PrintPrivate( void ){cout << m_i << endl; }
private:
    int m_i;
};

struct Point_f { 
  typedef int Point::*type;
  friend type get(Point_f);
};
template struct Rob<Point_f, &Point::m_i>;

void ChangePrivate ( Point &i ) 
{  
    i.*get(Point_f()) = 4;
}
```

[Sample on ideone.](http://ideone.com/rpyuvp)

Comment: Why the access of &Point::m_i can succeed ?

Comment: It would also be nice if you explained `typedef int Point::*type;` and how `&Point::m_i` matches that type. I've never seen a declaration like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 void ChangePrivate ( Point &i ) { *(int*)( ((char*)&i) + 0 ) += 1; }
```

Replace 0 with offsetof() if applicable or custom-calculated offset.

Or something like

```
struct HackPoint
{
  int m_i;
};

void ChangePrivate ( Point &i ) { ((HackPoint*)(void*)&i)->m_i++; }
```

Comment: I appreciate all the downvotes coming soon ;-)

Comment: IMO There's nothing wrong with suggesting code that's possibly unsafe or not portable or bad practice, as long as it's labeled as such and solves the OP's problem. Let the buyer beware!

Comment: @queen3 references `offsetof()`, whose definition can be found here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
*(int*)(&sPoint) += 1;
```

Instead of

```
ChangePrivate(sPoint);
```

But it's not a good coding style, just for fun.

*Inside the C++ Object Model*  This book gives detailed analysis about C++ object model

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That's why I say "just for fun". But actually it just a simple struct which has only one member. so this may work on most compiler. :)

Comment: queen3's answer offers a more generalized solution with a known offset, instead of a zero-offset.